# Group concat function in mysql dont give results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want the user_name from a table by joining user_m to approval_master.
The user_name in approval_master is in the form of string
like

```
'abcd1234','pqrs1234'.
```

I want the names of those users
like

```
abcd,pqrs
```

The usernames are in a column called LEVEL_1.
This is my query

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.Name), am.id, c.DEPARTMENT_DESC
from approval_master am join
     cost_center_lov c
     on c.DEPARTMENT_ID = am.DEPARTMENT join
     user_m u 
    on FIND_IN_SET(u.User_Name, am.LEVEL_1)
group by am.id
```

The result of query
select LEVEL_1 from approval_master is

```
'md2188','admin'
'md2188'
```

The result of query
select user_name, name from user_m is

```
user_name   name
-----------------
Admin       Admin
md2188      MD
```

I want my result to be

```
MD,Admin
MD
```

Result: Nothing!!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Comment: done Sir, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your FIND_IN_SET function is returning data. Take out the group_concat function from the query, and just search for "select distinct u.name, am.id, c.department_desc...."

Comment: Thank You, the problem were the single quotes in the string